# Meaning of "who bespoke our place so far in the east"

Tags: meaning, aurora-leigh, elizabeth-barrett-browning

From *[Aurora Leigh](http://digital.library.upenn.edu/women/barrett/aurora/aurora.html#1)*:

> So it is:
>   We covet for the soul, the body's part,
>   To die and rot. Even so, Aurora, ends
>   Our aspiration, **who bespoke our place
>
>   So far in the east**.

What is the meaning of "who bespoke our place so far in the east"? What possibly could it mean?

As an aside, is there a good version of "Aurora Leigh" online with a parallel translation into plain English, i.e. with comments and annotations? It's well-nigh impossible to understand a good third of the poem.

Comment: Almost certainly, it is an allusion to Christ. It is the Middle East, not the Far East, that the poet is referring to.

Comment: @Mick - thank you, but I don't get the structure of the phrase yet. What is "who bespoke our place"? The aspiration of us, who ... did what? "To bespeak" = "to order"?

Comment: *Bespeak* probably means either to *proclaim* or to *foretell* in this context. However, I have absolutely no expertise with such recondite poetry. The poet seems to be addressing the desirability of annihilation following death, but her conclusion is not evident from the text. On the whole, I prefer dancing with daffodils.

Comment: @Mick - what is "dancing with daffodils"?

Comment: Tennyson -- *I Wandered Lonely as a Cloud* (it's an easy read). Actually, Robert Frost's *Stopping by Woods on a Snowy Evening* would have been more appropriate (and it is one of my favourite poems).

Comment: You do realise that you are going to be the site's official expert on EBB by the time you've finished this poem, don't you?

Comment: @Mick - I love some of Liz Browning's poems and decided to read Aurora Leigh through. I never thought it would seem recondite to a native speaker. To me, it's as dense as concrete in many places. I understand maybe 50%, the rest is dull mouthing of poorly connected words. No, I'll not become an expert. Haha ))

Comment: Tennyson?!!! Doh! I meant Wordsworth.

Comment: @Mick - if you have an answer, why not post it below as an actual answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won’t claim to have the definitive answer, but one recurring theme in the poem is the morning sun as the source of the soul and of divine inspiration.  Aurora is even called out within the poem as a name that means the dawn.  Some instances of it include Aurora opening the window and her soul to the morning sun, Marian having been born to humble origins, but facing the east and inspired by some spirit, and Aurora’s suitor calling her a “Chaldean” who loves her “Eastern” books (meaning ancient Greek; Chaldea is now part of modern Turkey).  There are some other references to the east in the poem, like her saying that her aunt who wants her to say yes to his proposal is blowing a wind from the east, and perhaps to the garden east of Eden.

In context, the previous stanza is talking about something like Plato’s conception of the soul (to which there are many allusions in the poem) and the next is talking about aspiring to be closer to God.  So the metaphor is, at least in part, about humans as coming from the east and wandering, like beasts, to the west in search of food and comfort. while our higher selves aspire to return.